# What's wrong with my Dialog box and how should I change arraylist from different class and on separate .java file?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, arraylist, dialog

I am trying to write a GUI program that will import a text file, read its content and put them into ArrayList.

I write the panel in a separate .java file  that contain the import button and perform the import function, while the Arraylist is on the different .java file (main method ones).

How should I make ActionListener to read and import file contents into ArrayList from different class/.java file?

My import dialog box alos causes error, what's wrong with it?  The code works fine in CLI but not in GUI program.

**This is the main method of GUI Frame, it will add the panel from different .java file:**

```
public class FrameGUI 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {

        //Creates ArrayList and initiating JFrame
        ArrayList<String> stringFile = new ArrayList<String>();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Title");


        *//Rest of the following codes here*        


    }  //---End of Main Method---


} ---End of the First .java file
```

**This is the second .java file, which contains panel with import button and performing the action, read the contents of .txt file and import them into arraylist:**

```
public class ImportPanel extends JPanel
{

    private JButton importButton;

    public ImportPanel(ArrayList<String> StringFile)
    {

    //Setting up JButton and link it to inner class of
    //ActionListener
    importButton = new JButton("Import Data");
    importButton.addActionListener(new importListener());


    *//***Adding the button into panel, set background color and panel size*

}  //---End of main method---


    //Private inner class:
    private class importListener implements ActionListener
    {

        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
        {

            //---Import Function---
            //The following statement will ask the user for input first 
            //BEFORE it displays title and JFrame
            //Setting the file type, showing the dialog box:
            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
            FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("TEXT FILES",
                    "txt","text"); //only allows user to import .txt files
            chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
            int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);


            //Execute the following and import data
            //if the file type match:
            Scanner fileScan;
            String stringAdd;

            if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File inputFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
                fileScan = new Scanner(inputFile);

                //Scan the first line as title:
                //-disable-frame = new JFrame (fileScan.nextLine());


                //Parsing the data into Arraylist
                while (fileScan.hasNext())
                {

                    stringAdd = fileScan.nextLine();
                    StringFile.add(new String(stringAdd));

                } }  //End of the if statement- 

        }



    }  //---End of private inner class---


}  //End of the second .java file
```

I have tried to search before asking for question, I know that in order to change variable on different class, we need to add something called reference.  But I don't know how to add and where to add in this case, when the classes are on two different .java file, rather than one.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  An SSCCE can have more than one class, but they all must be in the same source file, with only one of the classes (the one with `main` method) declared `public`.

Answer (score 0):

In your `ImportPanel` class how did you use that `StringFile` `ArrayList` object in `importListener` inner class?
Here `StringFile` is a local object for `ImportPanel()` constructor. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference) for understanding pass by reference in java. In your case I prefer using a single `public static ArrayList<String> StringFile;` object in one class and use it in all other classes.